# C# and JQuery, strange behaviour on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-2.0, postback

I have an asp.net web site in which I'm trying to insert some ajax call to gain some loading time on page opening.

SCENARIO:
On page A.aspx I use JQuery $(document).ready() event to trigger an ajax call (via the ajax() method). The ajax call targets B.aspx page (in the same site) which renders a portion of html that I eventually inject into the existing markup of A.aspx.

After that ajax call the page is not able to fire __dopostback event properly anymore. In fact if I try to click to a pre-existing control in page A.aspx that should trigger a page postback B.aspx page is opened instead.

I tried to move B.aspx to another site, which runs in another application pool, but __dopostback call on A.aspx still tries to open B.aspx .

Here's the call:

```
    
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "./B.aspx",
            data:"username=xxx",
            dataType: "text",
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                $('#agentResultErrorContainer').html('Error... ' + errorThrown);
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#agentsResultContainer').html(data);
            }
        });
...
...
...
    }
```

Other details:
Site runs under .net 2.0 platform

Answer (score 1):

The way you're doing it here, you end up with two of every element ASP.NET: two viewstates, two forms (with the name name and id), JavaScript functions, etc (see also [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654270)). This, by the way, has nothing to do with the app-pool, it all happens client-side.
Also, even if you do a successful postback, you're likely to get various exceptions.

The solution? Don't do it. You can move on to MVC, where this is more comfortable, or more likely, you can create `b.ashx` (a general handler), that returns clean HTML (with no postbacks), and handle the logics using Javascript, or using the fields being posted to `a.aspx`. (you can add input fields and read them using `Request.Form`).

Another note: I doubt this approach will get you a better user experience - they still have to wait for the page to load, and it is likely to be even *slower*. I'll give you the same advice I gave at the other question - a user control is the simplest solution here.

Comment: I agree with Kobi, the postback failure is certainly because of the double controls.  I would consider creating an .ashx as Kobi suggests without any of the server-side mark-up. This should solve your problem.

Further, Kobi has raised a valid point about the AJAX call, firstly Jquery has to load (meaning the DOM has fully loaded) to make the call and secondly, you then have to wait for a second round-trip to the server for the page.

Answer (score 0):

What does B.aspx render? If it's a webform, then this is probably expected behaviour, as the hooks for __dopostback will be updated to point to B.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

@Kobi, @David: Thanks a lot for your explanations. There were form and viewstate replication also on the async-called page and were obviously injected on the original markup, causing the mess.

@Kobi: I agree with your advice, moving to other paradigm, such as MVC, would surely be more effective, but unfortunately by now I can only try these small changes, leaving everything else as is.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you leave both pages on the same domain, I would suggest the following:

1. With regard to the $.ajax url property "./B.aspx", is the "." necessary?  I am used to using full relative paths (i.e. "/B.aspx" by itself).
2. Have you tried firing up your debugger, and placing breakpoints on Page_Load for both A.aspx and also B.aspx?   It may help you to deduce where the request is taking place and what is happening.
3. Are you using a plug-in like Firebug (for Firefox), or Web Developer Tools (for IE8)?  These tools will help you pinpoint any javascript errors.  I find that if a Javascript error is fired on a page, it may prevent future javascript functions (such as __DoPostback) to not occur because the script as abnormally ended.

Hope those suggestions help.